# Changing drives in near future, for an ssd in a server

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

How is it possible to transfer all files including all server files without having to reinstall Cloudron and setup Cloudron all over again. Is there an special terminal command like if i connect external drive it would transfer all files to external drive and makes correct partition and such

Comment: it might work or not, but clonezilla save drive and restore drive might do it. you might need to use gparted to work on the partition sizes before, or after doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot with an install drive then in then `Terminal` use.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sd? of=/dev/sd*
```

Replacing the ? with the drive letter of the already installed disk, the * with the new `SSD`. This will exactly copy everything including the partition table to the new drive. The new drive needing to be at least the same size as the drive it replaces or it will fail. If larger size you would need to resize the partition(s) to regain the lost space.

Alternatively you can partition the new drive then use the `rsync` program to copy just the information on the drive not all the blank space like the `dd` method does. Once you have it partitioned like it needs to be.

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/old
sudo mkdir /tmp/new
sudo mount /dev/sd?1 /tmp/old
sudo mount /dev/sd*1 /tmp/new
sudo rsync -avP /tmp/old/* /tmp/new/
```

That for a one partition setup with the first (1) partition containing the `/` partition. You would replace the ? with the drive letter of the old install, the * with the new drive letter. Once done you would need to remove the old drive install the new and boot with the install usb drive to run the boot-repair to re-install `GRUB`.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair